# collections.Counter, is there any way to avoid adding string values?

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, counter

For example, I have two dictionaries.

```py
>>> dict_a = {'total': 20, 'remaining': 10, 'group': 'group_a'}
>>> dict_b = {'total': 30, 'remaining': 29, 'group': 'group_a'}
```

I am using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for counting purposes.

```
>>> dict_c = Counter()
>>> dict_c.update(Counter(dict_a))
>>> dict_c.update(Counter(dict_b))
>>> print(dict_c)
{'toal': 50, 'remaining': 39, 'group': 'group_agroup_a'}
```

Is there any way to add only integer type values? i.e when added it adds up integer type values only.

```
>>> print(dict_c)
>>> {'toal': 50, 'remaining': 39, 'group': 'group_a'}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Running your code, I'm getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'`

Comment: I have updated the code. @zamir I have added expected output at the end.

Comment: You can't add dictionaries like that, so your example of what you're now getting can't be correct.

Comment: @martineau I am using Counter from collections for adding. why can't it be correct? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I assumed that's the `Counter` you're using. I made my comment because the statement `dict_c = Counter(dict_a) + Counter(dict_b)` results in `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`. There's also typos in what you show as the displayed results, which further proves that it's fake.

Comment: I am sorry. I have actually used update method which resulted in the output. I thought + would do the same. Thanks.

Comment: Srikanth: In that case I think you ought update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own function to add two `Counter`objects like the ones you have in your question. This is necessary because the default method for adding `Counter` objects can't handle non-numeric values in them like you're putting in yours.

```
from collections import Counter

def add_counters(a, b):
    """ Add numerical counts from two Counters. """
    if not isinstance(a, Counter) or not isinstance(a, Counter):
        return NotImplemented
    result = Counter()
    for elem, count in a.items():
        newcount = count + b[elem]
        try:
            if newcount > 0:
                result[elem] = newcount
        except TypeError:
            result[elem] = count  # Just copy value.

    for elem, count in b.items():
        if elem not in a and count > 0:
            result[elem] = count

    return result


dict_a = {'total': 20, 'remaining': 10, 'group': 'group_a'}
dict_b = {'total': 30, 'remaining': 29, 'group': 'group_a'}
dict_c = add_counters(Counter(dict_a), Counter(dict_b))
print(dict_c)  # -> Counter({'total': 50, 'remaining': 39, 'group': 'group_a'})
```

Note that the above may not be totally correct because any non-numeric items in the first `Counter` argument `a` that are just copied to the result may get overwritten by the second `for` loop so their final value be whatever's in the second `Counter` named `b`. It's that way because you haven't defined precisely what you want to happen in a case like that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to add only integer type values?

This may not be the most efficient solution, but you can simply iterate through the key-value pairs of `dict_c` to check if the values are of type `int` to create a new dictionary that only contains integer values.

```py
from collections import Counter

dict_a = {'total': 20, 'remaining': 10, 'group': 'group_a'}
dict_b = {'total': 30, 'remaining': 29, 'group': 'group_a'}
dict_c = Counter(dict_a) + Counter(dict_b)
dict_result = {key: value for key, value in dict_c.items() if isinstance(value, int)}
print(dict_result)
```

This returns the expected result:

```py
{'total': 50, 'remaining': 39}
```